# Exporting data to predefined excel in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, export-to-excel

I need to export data into user defined excel using MVC. I don't want to use tools like aspose etc.

Please help me in exporting data into user defined excel using MVC

Answer (score 2):

Try using openxml or closedxml.

check the following link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692092/A-free-Export-to-Excel-Csharp-class-using-OpenXML

http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/export-data-to-excel-using-openxml-sdk/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42628/Using-ASP-NET-MVC-and-the-OpenXML-API-to-Stream-Ex

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit I am new to MVC. or if you can share a example or link that will be great

Comment: i have updated the answer with links related to openxml.